# Graphql always returns null

Tags: node.js, mongoose, graphql

I'm trying to get data from a mongodb collection using graphql and mongoose but graphql always resolves to null. This is the query I am trying:

getUser(email: "john@gmail.com"){
       name
}

```
const userModel = new Mongoose.model("db.users", {
    _id: String,
    email: String,
    name: String
});

const userType = new GraphQLObjectType({
    name: "user",
    fields : {
        _id: {type: GraphQLID},
        email: {type: GraphQLString},
        name: {type: GraphQLString}

    }
});


// Construct a schema
const schema = new GraphQLSchema({

    query: new GraphQLObjectType({
        name:"query",
        fields: {
            getUser: {
                type: userType,
                args: {
                    email: {
                        type: GraphQLString,
                    }
                },
                resolve: async(root, args, context, info) => {
                    return await(userModel.findOne(args).exec());

                }               
            }
        }
    })
});
```

Comment: I think it's a type problem, you id for mongodb is a string and for graphql it's GraphQLID, and I don't undrestand why you are specifying and id for your mongo schema are you going to set id's manually on every update? otherwise, you can delete this field because mongo automatically set the id

Comment: I've already tried removing the id fields but it still poses the same problem